# convert \special to PS/PDF file

Tags: postscript

I have a TeX file containing only one large `\special{...}` command, supposedly containing PostScript code.

```
\special{!userdict begin 
% DSB: start-hook to etna-start-hook
/etna-start-hook{gsave 
80 780 translate
/Times-Bold findfont 7 scalefont setfont
26 -20 moveto 
(Electronic Transactions on Numerical Analysis.)
gsave show grestore 
/Times-Bold findfont 7 scalefont setfont
26 -30  moveto
(Volume 40, pp. 249-267, 2013.) 
gsave show grestore 
/Times-Bold findfont 7 scalefont setfont
26 -40 moveto
(Copyright)
gsave show grestore 
/Symbol findfont 7 scalefont setfont
59 -40 moveto
<D3>
gsave show grestore 
/Times-Bold findfont 7 scalefont setfont
67 -40 moveto
(2013, Kent State University.)
gsave show grestore 
/Times-Bold findfont 7 scalefont setfont
26 -50 moveto
(ISSN 1068-9613.)
gsave show grestore 
grestore}def 
/bop-hook{
% DSB: At start of page, check if we're on page 0; if so, run etna-start-hook
dup 0 eq {etna-start-hook} if
gsave
1 setlinecap 1 setlinejoin
%-13 13 translate
-13 33 translate
0.000000 477.000000 translate 0.900 -0.900 scale
1.000 setlinewidth
% Polyline
newpath 544 -251 moveto 544 -286 lineto 451 -286 lineto 451 -251 lineto closepath  stroke
/Times-Bold  findfont 12.000 scalefont setfont
%/Palatino-Bolditalic findfont 14.000 scalefont setfont 
497 -275 moveto 
1 -1 scale
(ETNA)dup stringwidth pop 2 div neg 0 rmoveto  gsave  0.000 rotate show grestore 1 -1 scale
/Times-Bold findfont 8.000 scalefont setfont
%/Palatino-Bolditalic findfont 14.000 scalefont setfont
499 -265 moveto 
1 -1 scale
(Kent State University )dup stringwidth pop 2 div neg 0 rmoveto  gsave  0.000 rotate show grestore 1 -1 scale
%/Times-BoldItalic findfont 20.000 scalefont setfont
/Times-Bold findfont 8.000 scalefont setfont
498 -255 moveto 
1 -1 scale
(http://etna.math.kent.edu)dup stringwidth pop 2 div neg 0 rmoveto  gsave  0.000 rotate show grestore 1 -1 scale
grestore}def end}
```

I would like to convert this file into a proper PostScript (and then PDF) file.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is that all that is in the `.tex` file?  In any case, `dvips` followed by `ps2pdf` should be happy to convert.

Comment: @JosephWright Tried that, didn't work. I guess the PS file has to start out with `%!PS`, but even then this doesn't seem to be legal PostScript code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only missing bit is a closing

```
\bye
```

at the end of the code. The command sequence `tex`, `dvips`, `ps2pdf` ŕun on the code produces valid Postscript and PDF.